# Roslaunch got "No such file or directory" while starting a node

Tags: python, ros, catkin

I'm creating my own node for ROS that is written in python. When I start the node `roslaunch contact_charging contact_charging.launch` I get this error:

```
Roslaunch got a 'No such file or directory' error while attempting to run:
/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/contact_charging/nodes/contact_charging.py __name:=contact_charging __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/709588cc-7a39-11ea-9bb6-77211eadb622/contact_charging-5.log
Please make sure that all the executables in this command exist and have
executable permission. This is often caused by a bad launch-prefix.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

launch file */src/contact_charging/launch/contact_charging.launch*:

```
<launch>

    <include file="$(find magni_nav)/launch/move_basic.launch"/>
    <include file="$(find magni_description)/launch/description.launch"/>
    <include file="$(find raspicam_node)/launch/camerav2_1280x960.launch" />


    <node pkg="contact_charging" type="contact_charging.py" name="contact_charging" output="screen"></node>

</launch>
```

Python script is located in */src/contact_charging/nodes/contact_charging.py*

What I tried so far:

1. chmod 777 /contact_charger -R
2. Catkin_make several times and restarted the machine/terminal
3. Created setup.py in root folder

Comment: Does the pkg exist? Have sourced it?

Comment: You wrote `chmod 777 /contact_charger -R` but your package is called `contact_charging`. You can double check that your executable has the correct permissions: `roscd contact_charging; ls -l nodes/contact_charging.py`. If not, set them with `chmod +x nodes/contact_charging.py` , then try to run the node only with `rosrun contact_charging contact_charging.py`